# How can I set delay between code lines in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.

I have `form1` with 3 `buttons`. I am trying to set the 3 buttons so they appear one by one when/after the form loads . I used the following code but it did not work when I run the program the 3 buttons appear in the same time

```
 private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    //Hide all buttons
        button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
        button3.Visible = false;


        Thread.Sleep(500);

       //show buttons one by one
        button1.Visible = true;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        button2.Visible = true;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        button3.Visible = true;


    }
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me how can I make the 3 buttons appear one by one when/after the form loads. I am happy to receive any other ideas . Thank you

Comment: if you don't mind my asking, why?

Comment: I would guess that the Load event happens before the render event, so this code will just make the form take some time to load, but when it's rendered the method has already returned

Comment: When the Form_Load event executes the form is not visible. Move the settings to visible in the Form_Shown event, but as @DanielA.White asks. Why?

Comment: @ Daniel A. White . because I am designing something like effects in the dashboard where buttons appear one by one. I do not know if it's the right way to do it. any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue here is that Load is called before the form is rendered. This, combined with the fact that Thread.Sleep blocks the current (UI) thread causes the buttons to all be made visible before the form actually renders.

You can solve this by using the `Form.Shown` event and making your pauses asynchronous.

```
private async void Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var buttons = new[] {button1, button2, button3};
    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        button.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Make sure that your buttons still get initiated with `Visible = false;`

Comment: Sorry I am confused, I copied this function ( async void Shown) as it's in the form Can you tell me what to write in Form.Shown event?

Comment: this is the event handler. this is the method handler you want to invoke when the form fires the `Shown` event. the method should probably be renamed to `MainForm_Shown` though.

Answer (score 6):

You are blocking the UI thread with Thread.Sleep, and the updates aren't being reflected.

The best you can do is to create an async function and use Task.Delay, in this way the thread will be still responsive and you will see the updates:

```
private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    //Hide all buttons
    button1.Visible = false;
    button2.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = false;


    await Task.Delay(500);

   //show buttons one by one
    button1.Visible = true;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    button2.Visible = true;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    button3.Visible = true;


}
```

Comment: I think this might work, although with a race condition. Since Load is called before the Form is rendered, the tasks may have already completed before the form is rendered. running the code on Shown is more semantically correct and will work better.

Comment: There will be no problem because all is done after InitializeComponents, but yes, semantically speaking would be better to use Show, but for this example I belive is clearer to just update what the user posted with the async method

Comment: there will be problems if for some reason the code run between Load and Shown takes a significant portion of 500 ms. something that isn't all too likely, but might very well happen if the Load event also does some sort of resource allocation, fetching data from the Internet or does some I/O. I think it's bad practice in general to encourage UI animation in the Load event, since that is not what it's for and it can lead to problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Visible of all buttons to False in Form_Load event as you do. 
Create a timer with the desired interval and some counter. 
Inside the Timer.Tick event, set visibility of your buttons one by one, depending on the counter value, like this:

```
switch(counter)
{
  case 0:  button1.Visible = true; break;
  case 1:  button2.Visible = true; break;
  case 2:  button3.Visible = true; break;
}
counter++;
```

Then when all your buttons are visible, disable the timer.

Answer (score 0):

```
            button1.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = false;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { button1.Visible = true; });

                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { button2.Visible = true; });
            });
```